# Does EVT imply IVT?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Here I define Intermediate Value Property (IVP) and Extreme Value Property (EVP) as follows:

- IVP: If $I$ is an interval, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we say that 
  $f$ has the intermediate value property iff whenever $a<b$ are points in $I$ and $f(a)\leq c\leq f(b)$, there is a $d$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(d)=c$.
- EVP: If $I$ is an interval, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we say that $f$ has the extreme value property iff $f$ has maximum and minimum value, each at least once. That is, $\exists a,b\in I$ such that $f(a)\leq f(x) \leq f(b)$ for all $x\in I$.

My question is, does EVP imply IVT? How can I prove it? Cheers!

Comment: @lhf: I'm pretty sure the OP is talking about these as properties of a function $f$.

Comment: Counterexample: $I = (-1, 1)$, $f(x) = \begin{cases} x-1, & x < 0 \\ x + 1, & x \ge 0. \end{cases}$

Comment: You must want to assume the continuity of $f$, else on $[0, 1]$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x =0$, $f(x) = 1$ otherwise - this satisfies EVP but not IVT

Comment: Even in case of continuous functions, these properties are independent. But both of them (like any other serious theorem of analysis) are consequences of completeness of real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your question as follows:

> If a function $f$ satisfies EVP on an interval $I$, does it follow that the same function $f$ satisfies IVP on the same interval $I$?

Then the answer is **NO**. Here's an example on $I=[0,1]$:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x\in [0,1/2]; \\ 5 & x\in (1/2,1]. \end{cases}$$

It satisfies the EVP but not the IVP.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to add the continuity condition (sorry!). If we have this condition, will it hold? How can we prove it? Cheers!

Comment: @AngghaNugraha: Yes, with continuity it does hold. Hint: apply the regular IVT on the closed interval $[a,b]$ or $[b,a]$ (whichever makes sense), where $a$ and $b$ come from your EVT property.

Comment: Hmm I don't quite get it. So the idea is: suppose that $f$ is a function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and $f$ has minimum and maximum value on $[a,b]$.We want to prove that $\forall c$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there exist $d$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(d)=c$, right? What do you mean by "apply the regular IVT on the closed interval $[a,b]$"? Which one is the regular IVT?

Comment: A continuous function always has the IVP on  any interval $I$ that is a subset of its domain.

Comment: @zipirovich Should I have something that guarantee that $f$ also have maximum and minimum value on every subinterval of $[a,b]$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous it will attain a max and min  on every closed interval. But suppose $f(x)=0$ when $x\in \mathbb Q$, and $f(x)=1$ when $x\in \mathbb R \backslash  \mathbb Q.$ Then $f$ attains a max and min on any non-empty interval but f does not have the IVP.

Comment: @AngghaNugraha: My comment above was ... uhmm ... not exactly accurate. (Well, nobody's perfect.) Here's what I should've said. If $f$ is continuous, then $f$ satisfies the IVT on **any** interval $I$ -- simply because as soon as we pick two points $a,b\in I$, $a<b$, we're dealing with a continuous function $f$ on the closed bounded interval $[a,b]$, and the IVT holds (see any standard Calculus textbook). The EVT, however, holds automatically only on closed bounded intervals, but not necessarily on other intervals. Quick example: $f(x)=1/x$ on $I=(0,+\infty)$.